# Different iOS devices size programming approach

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am starting a new project which should be working on every iOS device size possible.

The project is rather simple. The main view will be a scroll view and it will hold a '+' button (where it says 'button' in the image) in the top right corner. (It does not really matter, I'm just trying to give the general idea of what I'm trying to understand and implement.)

A small example:

[image]

What is the right approach for this kind of problem?
Should I create a different storyboard for each device? 
Should I start creating an adjustable scroll view that will hold the needed buttons with some constraints (if at all possible)?

I have read this tutorial:

[auto layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

which explains the auto layout nicely, but does not mention the issue I'm trying to figure out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: AutoLayout is the right start.  Read up on "Size Classes" and that should complete the picture for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use AutoLayout and position your views relative to one another (so no x pixels spacing between views). Make only one storyboard for all devices, when a different view should be loaded on another device (like a completely different layout), select the appropriate [size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html) and adapt the views and constraints.

Then it will be recalculated on every device.

The storyboard has a preview section where you can choose a device to simulate the view on.